# Determine if font as a system font on macOS using public API

Tags: objective-c, macos

There are two *private* undocumented functions from the macOs API to determine if the font is a system font.

```
CTFontIsSystemUIFont(CTFontRef);
CTFontDescriptorIsSystemUIFont();
```

Is there any documented *public* function for that, smth like `bool isSystemFont(CTFontRef)`?